# system running slow after running my code

Tags: android

I am writing a small piece of code.  However, the system became so slow after running it a few times.  The system will have a hard time even when I am at the home screen and try to swipe.  So I guess I have some memory leak.

The code is really simple.  It has a database, and a content provider build on the db.  The View consist of 2 list view and a button.  When I hit the button, a dialog pop up for me to input 2 string.  then the strings are put into the database, one of the list is forced to refresh.  When I tried to use ddms to look at the VM heap, I am seeing "data object" counts in the 22k.  2byte array in the 8k range, and 4byte array in the 3k range...this seems like a lot.  Can anyone give me some suggestion? or know of a place where I can dump the code for others to see... thanks

Comment: Check to make sure you have no runaway loops would be the first thought; make sure all the loops / whiles / etc actually stop running

Comment: Force close the application and Android should clean up, if that's really the problem